# Get all files under subfolder in Shared Documents list - SP Object Model

Tags: document-library, client-object-model, caml

I am trying to get all files in a subfolder, in the Document Library "Shared Documents" in SP 2010.

So the structure looks like

```
http://sp2010site/sitename/shared documents/folder1/
http://sp2010site/sitename/shared documents/folder2/
http://sp2010site/sitename/shared documents/folder3/
```

I want to get all files under folder1, for example.

I need to use sp client object model unfortunately.

I keep getting a really unhelpful exception

> "value does not fall within range"

any ideas how to get all files under Folder1?

```
//rootList is string "Shared Documents"

using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(m_siteUrl))
            {
                List list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(rootList);
                CamlQuery caml = new CamlQuery();
                caml.ViewXml = @"<View Scope='Recursive'>
                                    <Query>
                                    </Query>
                                </View>";
                caml.FolderServerRelativeUrl = "/Shared Documents/Folder1";
                ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(caml);
                ctx.Load(listItems);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery(); //exception throws here

                ListItem itemOfInterest = listItems[0];
                string creator = itemOfInterest.FieldValues["Created_x0020_By"].ToString();
                string title = itemOfInterest.FieldValues["Title"].ToString();
```

**EDIT**:

I'm getting close

```
var folders = ctx.Web.Folders;
                ctx.Load(folders);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                var theone = folders.Where(x => x.ServerRelativeUrl == "/sitename/Shared Documents");


// folders definetly loads and has all the folders, but I can't seem to do linq on it to just get the one I care about... WHY?
```

since i can't use LINQ i'm forced to do a foreach untill i find it...there must be a better way? because then once i've found the root folder (i.e. shared documents), i then need to loop through each subfolder in the same fashion... :-S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [CamlQuery.FolderServerRelativeUrl property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.camlquery.folderserverrelativeurl%28v=office.15%29.aspx) expects server relative URL of a list folder to be specified, try to specify it's value using the following format: `/<WebRelativeUrl>/<ListUrl>/<FolderUrl>`

Example:

```
caml.FolderServerRelativeUrl = "/sitename/Shared Documents/Folder1";
```

That will do the trick of getting list items from a specific folder.