# How to get all files from the subfolder?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

Hi everyone I have a Folder1 in my Server and inside that folder I have a Folder2 folder. So I am getting the file which is inside the Folder1 with this code:

```
public static SPClient.ListItemCollection GetPageItems(string listName = "Folder1")
{

    var pagesList = SharePointTools.ClientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
    var pageItems = pagesList.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
    SharePointTools.ClientContext.Load(pageItems);
    SharePointTools.ClientContext.Load(pageItems, list => list.Include(page => page.DisplayName));
    SharePointTools.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    return pageItems;
}
```

So it is using GetByTitle method but I can't get the files which is inside my Folder2. So how I can get all files inside my Folder2?
Can someone answer?

Comment: What makes you think you cannot get items from `Folder2`  sub folder in your example? `CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery` returns all the items including from sub folders..

Answer (score 3):

Try to use Caml Query with `FolderServerRelativeUrl` property

```
caml.FolderServerRelativeUrl = "/sitename/Documents/Folder1";
```

For more details check [Get all files under subfolder in Shared Documents list - SP Object Model](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/101783/get-all-files-under-subfolder-in-shared-documents-list-sp-object-model)

Or using `SPQuery`

```
SPFolder folder = list.RootFolder.SubFolders["Folder 1"];
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.Folder = folder;
query.ViewAttributes = "Scope=\"Recursive\"";
```

For more details check [Get all Files from sub folder of a certain content type](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/59216/get-all-files-from-sub-folder-of-a-certain-content-type)

Comment: **OP** has asked for **CSOM** not **SOM**